# How do I make it so that a user must either enter text or select a check box on Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

I am using salesforce for a group project here at SJSU, the thing is this is our first time using it, and we are having a little bit of trouble programming some things on Salesforce.

What we are trying to do:

We have a section on one of our forms where users will give us authorization to use Data they submit, the usage of this data will be under the terms set by those who submit the data. If the user does not want to set limitations on their authorization for us to use the data then they can select a checkbox called labeled "none" which basically means they are setting no limitations on what we can use their data for.

What we want to do is, if users select the checkbox then we want the users to not be able to enter any text into the textbox. If users enter text into the box while the checkbox is checked we want an error message to appear which will let the user know that no data can be entered into the box if the checkbox is checked. However if no checkbox is checked then we want users to be able to enter the data. How do we go about doing this

```
AND (None_c = True then Limitations_c has to be empty, elseif None_c = False then Limitations_c cannot be empty.)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leverage the out of the box UI (Page Layout), then you will likely want to use Validation Rules.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_defining_field_validation_rules.htm&language=en_US

The gist of it is that you want to define **Error** criteria, so when this criteria evaluates to true, and error is thrown. In that case, you should be able to construct something similar to the following:

```
Checkbox1__c && NOT(ISBLANK(Text2__c))
```

Answer (score 0):

Validation rules would be the easiest way to execute this, though checking the box would not dynamically prevent users from entering text.  With a validation rule, it just wouldn't let a users save.

The nice thing about using validation rules is that you can construct them such that checking `None__c` will not vomit on the user unless they actually modify `Limitations__c`.  `ISCHANGED()` is great for that.

If I could suggest an alternative, the way I would implement this is to treat an empty `Limitations__c` as `None__c = True`.  It simplifies things for users, and you can add a formula-driven checkbox if a checkbox element is truly required.